# How to fetch latest branch from github and override existing codes?

Tags: git, github, branch

I am working on a project for the last couple of days. I did work on both my home computer as well as my office computer in my office.

I worked on my home computer 2 days ago and it has branch "002" codes, but I did continue work on this project and today I pushed those codes in branch "005" in the same git repo from my office computer.

How can I fetch the branch "005" from GitHub in the same folder on my home computer and override old codes "002 branch codes" as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From you home computer,

1. checkout branch "005" from GitHub to create a local branch "005" on your home computer.
2. change to the existing branch "002"
3. Merge branch "005" into "002"

Answer (score 0):

Just completing the answer from nbstrat:

From your home computer:

move to the most updated branch that has all the changes

```
git checkout 005
```

Get most recent version from remote repo

```
git pull
```

Merge the old branch you had in your home computer

```
git merge 002
```

Should be good to go.